# java.io.IOException: Too many open files kafka-rest proxy

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using confluent kafka platform . I have a topic with 4 partition and replication factor of 2. Single zookeeper, three brokers and kafka-rest proxy server. Now I am load testing the system with siege running 1000 users with a list of api which in turn hit kafka producer. I have my producer and consumer using the rest proxy ([kafka-rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-rest)). I am getting following issue:

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo EMFILE] code: 'EMFILE', errno: 'EMFILE', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

In kafka-rest log I can see:

```
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,972] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  14 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,973] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  15 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,974] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  12 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,978] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  6 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,983] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  6 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,984] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  4 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,985] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  7 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,993] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  3 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,994] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:07:13:51 +0000] "POST /topics/endsession HTTP/1.1" 200 120  4 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)
[2016-02-23 07:13:51,999] WARN Accept failed for channel java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed] (org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager:714)
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.processAccept(SelectorManager.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.processKey(SelectorManager.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.run(SelectorManager.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.NonBlockingThread.run(NonBlockingThread.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I went through a lot of questions related to this. Set my ec2 machine paramenters so that I dont get `too many open file error`. But its not solved. I have reduced the `TIME_WAIT` to 30 seconds. `ulimit -n` is 80000.

I have collected some stats and look like kafka rest proxy which is running on `localhost:8082 causing too many connections.
How do I solve this issue? Also sometimes when error is coming and then I stop my siege test but again when TIME_WAIT connections are reduced, I restart my load test with 1 user only still I see the same issue. Some issue in rest proxy wrapper for node js?

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the ulimit for that process. In order to check the ulimit for a particular process , run this:
sudo cat /proc/<*process_id*>/limits

in order to increase the ulimit for process running via supervisord, you can increase **minfds** in **supervisord.conf**